# Plastic Theme for PhpStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, phpstorm, color-scheme

Currently I'm using my favorite color scheme [Plastic](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=will-stone.plastic#overview) in Visual Studio Code and cannot find any alternative. I'm so in love with this theme so i want the same in PhpStorm.

Is there a simple way to convert VSCode Color Scheme to PhpStorm?

Comment: Cannot answer your actual question, but please check these links: 1) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Theme 2) Some quick way to see most of the themes (a contest held on Spring earlier this year): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/contest/intellij-themes/2019

Comment: @LazyOne i know the official theme links but could not find the Plastic theme or any other which is pleasant for the eyes like Plastic.

Comment: *"or any other which is pleasant for the eyes like Plastic"* That's very subjective. I agree, Plastic looks pleasant at first glance (on a screenshot) ... and I, for example, do like lots of themes (at very least when I see the code snippets/how it looks) .. but when I install any of them myself, I quickly find lots of issues with them (things that are missing in my plain theme, that I got used to for so many years).

Comment: **P.S** I may only suggest to install a few and check how they look, I think there is 1 or 2 that has some similar look (at least at quick glance).  You may create your own (or take some as basis and customize it further) .. but it will take some time. Just in case; this blog post has detailed links on how to customize it/make your own theme: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/03/brighten-up-your-day-add-color-to-intellij-idea/

Comment: Oh yes! Downloaded many themes and only some of them look good to me. I tried to recreate the theme with PhpStorm but i cannot recreate it with all details... It feels like VSCode has a more detailed syntax highlighting...?

Comment: Your feeling is correct. VSCode has a semantic highlighting system that is more granular in some areas (particularly around keywords). The highlighting system in Jetbrains IDEs is very complex due to the large amount of UI and languages supported, but it does have its shortcomings.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably no longer relevant for you, but I ported the theme and it's available for all Jetbrains IDEs.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18166-plastic